# ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) could not parse resource []

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I am attempting to load a csv file to my google cloud instance and followed their documentation I got this error:

`gcloud compute scp /Users/mark/Desktop/bus.csv my-fastai-instance:~/`

`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/fastai-229817/zones/us-east1-b/instances/my-fastai-instance' was not found`

This makes sense as I'm using a different zone so I added the correct zone and got this error:

`gcloud compute scp --zone= "us-east4-b" /Users/mark/Desktop/bus.csv my-fastai-instance:~/`

`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) could not parse resource []`

I know that the file is there and I'm not seeing anyone else have this problem.

Comment: Change to `--zone=us-east4-b`

Comment: Thanks that did it

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation for gcloud [scp](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) the correct syntax to specify a zone is '--zone=ZONE'

Answer (score 0):

Potentially unrelated, but I received this error when connecting with a username specified, in quotes ("). I

Did not work:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-central1-a "${user}@${instance_name_arg}"
```

Worked:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-central1-a ${user}@${instance_name_arg}
```